# Composer prompting me for key

Tags: macos, composer-php, ssh-keys

I recently updated my Macbook Pro to the latest Sierra build.

Now every time I run `composer update` I get prompted over and over for my password:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/julio/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Sometimes I get this ten or fifteen times. Is there a way to permanently unlock this, or at least unlock on login?

Comment: Could be issues with the ssh agent. Do any of these things help. https://github.com/jirsbek/SSH-keys-in-macOS-Sierra-keychain

Comment: @Doon-- thanks. `ssh-add -A` seemed to work for me. Not sure if I'll need to do that on each reboot however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above in @Doon's comment, executing the following unlocked the keychain for me:

```
ssh-add -A
```

I still don't know why this has changed in the latest Mac update or how to make this issue permanently go away-- at the moment I still have to issue this command after each reboot.

Comment: Inside docker : Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.